# How to know what does the function do?

Tags: ollydbg, x64dbg

I've made a simple c++ program. In the ollydbg i searching for the string which is my name, there are 2-3 call functions near the string location but i don't know what those function do.

My question is is there a way to know what those function do? is it print function or maybe other function?

[image: the program]

Comment: Could you upload your program and the resulting executable?

Comment: added:).........

Answer (score 0):

> i searching for the string

Presumably "`fffaaarrriiiddd`." So we find ourselves at `0x401538`, where the string is referenced.

> there are 2-3 call functions near the string location...
>   is is there a way to know what those function do? is it print function
>   or maybe other function?

The first call after `0x401538`, which is at `0x40154b` and calls to `0x46ec30` is the print function. We know this because it gets the string as an argument (see [x64 calling convention](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=vs-2019)) and because the call is followed by the struct accesses, as we would expect.

The second call after `0x401538` is correctly identified as a call to `getch` (or possibly a wrapper function that `jmp`'s to the imported DLL function).

The call before `0x401538`, which is at `0x401538` and calls to `0x40e760`, is less obvious. Because it is part of `main` but precedes the print function, which is the first call we expect based on the known functionality of `main`, I suspect it is just some sort of convention with which I am unfamiliar. Look at the disassembly at `0x40e760`. What does that function do? Try compiling a binary with a no/different functionality. Is there always a call in `main` after the stack setup? Or are there always two calls for `cout`?

Comment: So we can assume if there is a string at above the call then the it's the print function?, what if there's no string?

Comment: That's probably an oversimplification for which people could contrive counterexamples, but it's generally a good expectation. The print function has to get a value to print somehow. Looking at the arguments to the function, you will eventually trace one of them back to a string, even if it is less local to the call or indirected somehow.

Comment: Let say i got another call function and no string at above the call function, how do i know what func it would be?

Comment: The way I see it, the possible approaches for the general case are to 1) reverse engineer the functionality by looking at the disassembly/decompilation of the function in question -- this is called static analysis 2) if you have source code, you should be able to simply compile with debug symbols 3) if you have similar (or the same) source code, you could also use a tool like BinDiff 4) you could use dynamic analysis to match a function's behavior to the behavior of a known function.

Comment: For this example, we used static analysis (1). Debug symbols (2) is certainly a valid approach, which you might already have for free -- I don't know if OllyDbg displays them. As @bart1e suggests, another tool, such as IDA, might make this approach easier.

Comment: I don't know exactly how BinDiff (3) works, but it does take into account some of the same things we would look at using static analysis (e.g. from the known function `main`, what does the call graph look like?).

Comment: Dynamic analysis (4) could take many forms. You could use a debugger, and look at state changes as you step over instructions. Or you could ignore the implementation of the function itself and compare sets of test inputs and outputs to those of known functions. Those are just a couple examples.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation:) so the easiest way to go is by analyzing the register when breakpoint.

Comment: At below of the string the value of the address 48C690 is copied to ecx, why? In the dump there is the value of address 48C690 which is  .jH but i dont know what the correlation with the string

Answer (score 0):

First and easy way is to open the resulting executable in `IDA` which will just show you the function names for library functions.
[image: IDA_analysis]

Other still easy way is to just breakpoint before these function calls, step over these functions and observe the console output. You should be able to find at least `cout` this way. To do this in `x64dbg`, set up the breakpoint in the `main` function and keep clicking `Run` until you see it highlighted this way (that is `EIP` blue arrow in the same line as your breakpoint):
[image: x64dbgBreakpoint]

Then, keep clicking `Step over` until `EIP` is pointing on the first function call. Look at the console and click `Step over` once again. You should see that nothing happened there. Do the same thing with the subsequent function and after stepping over it, you will see the string being printed in the console.

Comment: I tried to breakpoint before the function calls then step over the function but why i got dragged to other function (DbgUiRemoteBreakin)

Comment: Are you sure that you used step over (not step into)?

Comment: Im pretty sure i clicked step over

Comment: I've updated my answer to better explain this process.

Comment: Thanks bart1e :), i would likely to ask ur opinion, Let say i got another call function and no string at above the call function, how do i know what func it would be other than you mention above?

Comment: The easiest approach is just to use more advanced tool (as IDA, Ghidra or radare2). It's the easiest way and will just save you a lot of work and recognise library functions. If it is not the library function or isn't recognised by these tools, you may do it by either static analysis (looking at the assembly) or using dynamic analysis (as I suggested in my answer). But if the function doesn't print anything on the screen, I would look firstly for the context where it was called, deduce from it what possibly does and confirm it by stepping into this function and see memory and register changes.

Comment: But it's a broad topic, so it's impossible to enumerate all methods to accomplish this. Just practice and you will gradually learn everything. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building your own code to understand the assembly, I suggest you use your compilers options to output an assembly listing. For example:

- [Microsoft Visual C++ Listing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/fa-fa-listing-file?view=msvc-160) using /FA option
- GCC use -Wa,-adhln -g option

You can also compile your program to include PDB files, and use freely available [WinDbg](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windbg-preview/9pgjgd53tn86) to step through code or disassembly line by line, easily viewing source code or disassembly.

Alternatively you can use [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) to quickly examine assembly code generated by various C/C++ compiler versions, with various optimizations and for different platforms